# map, but with newline characters between keypairs

Tags: json, jq, key-value

Say I have input like

```
{"DESCRIPTION": "Need to run script to do stuff", "PRIORITY": "Medium"}
```

but also get input like

```
{"STACK_NAME": "applecakes", "BACKEND_OR_INTEGRATIONS": "integrations", "PRIORITY": "Medium"}
```

ie, the parameters can be completely different.

I need to get the output in a format more friendly to send to Jira to make tickets. Specifically, I would like to strip the json formatting away, and insert a `\n` between each keypair. Here's what the above samples should look like:

```
DESCRIPTION: Need to run script to do stuff\nPRIORITY: Medium

STACK_NAME: applecakes\nBACKEND_OR_INTEGRATIONS: integrations\nPRIORITY: Medium
```

There can be a little flexibility in that if, for example, more spaces were needed or whatever.

So far I've got this worked out (assuming my input is stored in a variable called `description`

```
echo $description | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]"
```

This works to strip away the JSON formatting, but doesn't handle newlines. I'm stumped on how to make sure I split only on each keypair, not on say every space or anything equally messy. What do I need to add to include newlines? Is a map even my best choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just join what the array of strings with `\\n` (the sequence of the `\` character which we need to escape and the `n` character) and use raw-output :

```
jq --raw-output 'to_entries | map("\(.key) : \(.value)") | join("\\n")'
```

Try it [here](https://jqplay.org/s/OuD_TzOC6n).

Comment: can't believe I didn't find `join` in my googling - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or more efficiently and more simply:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value)"'
```

This produces one line per key-value pair.

### The two-character sequence `\n` as a join-string

With your sample JSON, the invocation:

```
 jq -j -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value)", "\\n" '
```

would produce:

```
STACK_NAME : applecakes\nBACKEND_OR_INTEGRATIONS : integrations\nPRIORITY : Medium\n
```

Notice the trailing "\n".

Comment: while you're completely correct that this prints on multiple lines (and wow that is simpler!), I actually need the output to have the `\n` in it, as it's being sent on to Jira

Comment: @Alex you shouldn't mention newline characters if what you need is a backslash followed by the letter n

Comment: @Aaron sorry about that, I thought "newline character" combined with my examples would make it clear enough. Perhaps I should have put it in code formatting? I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @Alex I would at least avoid using the singular for character, it made me think you wrote `\n` in order to make the linefeed characters visible and be more explicit. I think the term 'escape sequence' would be less ambiguous